# ios coredata How to check that rssfeed url is exist in coredata or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I want to setup like if rss feedurl available in coredata then only parsing is done else it will store in coredata.
I have try to implement method with reference of this question
[IOS Coredata check if attribute is exist or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259374/ios-coredata-check-if-attribute-is-exist-or-not)

Here is my Try:

```
- (void)feedParserDidFinish:(MWFeedParser *)parser {

    [HUD hide:YES];

    //**Coredata inserting value**//
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"maindata"];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchrequestforside=[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"anotherdata"];
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"urloffeed = %@", self.linkfeed];
    fetchrequestforside.predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"furloffeed = %@", self.linkfeed];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];





    if ([[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:NULL] count] == 0) {
        // Create a new managed object
        NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"maindata" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [newDevice setValue:self.Name forKey:@"urlname"];
        [newDevice setValue:self.WebsiteName forKey:@"websitename"];
        [newDevice setValue:self.Feedlink forKey:@"urloffeed"];


        NSError *error = nil;
        // Save the object to persistent store
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        }

    }

    if ([[context executeFetchRequest:fetchrequestforside error:NULL] count] == 0) {
        // Create a new managed object
               NSManagedObject *newDevice1 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"anotherdata" inManagedObjectContext:context];

        if (self.urlname) {
            [newDevice1 setValue:self.Name forKey:@"urlname"];

        }
        if (self.WebsiteName) {
            [newDevice1 setValue:self.WebsiteName forKey:@"websitename"];

        }
        if (self.urloffeed) {
            [newDevice1 setValue:self.Feedlink forKey:@"urloffeed"];

        }

        NSError *error = nil;
        // Save the object to persistent store
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        }

    }
```

Note:- I have to save url in two entity.

Comment: Use search query for url value in respective Column.

Comment: the only and best way  :  you should make a predicate and check this url on your DB before insert

Comment: can you please explain in detail i am new to ios so , i dont know how to set condition for check url in coredata ?

Comment: So, what are the results you get, and what are the results you expect?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to want to optionally insert entities based on the value of a particular attribute more than once, then you may want to write a helper method.

Something like this may do what you want.  It returns `YES` if the object was inserted.  In this case, `objectPtr` will contain the newly inserted object.  It returns `NO` if the object already exists, or if there was an error trying to perform the insert.  `objectPtr` will contain the existing object or `errorPtr` will contain the error.

```
- (BOOL)insertEntity:(NSString*)entity
           withValue:(id)value
              forKey:(NSString*)key
               inMOC:(NSManagedObjectContext*)moc
              object:(NSManagedObject**)objectPtr
               error:(NSError**)errorPtr {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entity];
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K = %@", key, value];
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1;
    BOOL inserted = NO;
    NSArray *result = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:errorPtr];
    if (result) {
        NSManagedObject *object = [result firstObject];
        if (object == nil) {
            object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entity
                                                   inManagedObjectContext:moc];
            [object setValue:value forKey:key];
            inserted = YES;
        }
        if (objectPtr) {
            *objectPtr = object;
        }
    } else if (objectPtr) {
        *objectPtr = nil;
    }
    return inserted;
}
```

Then, you can use it like so...

```
NSManagedObject *object;
NSError *error;
if ([self insertEntity:@"maindata"
             withValue:self.Feedlink
                forKey:@"urloffeed"
                 inMOC:context
                object:&object
                 error:&error]) {
    [object setValue:self.Name forKey:@"urlname"];
    [object setValue:self.WebsiteName forKey:@"websitename"];
}
```